# Internet explorer does not ask to save passwords or form data (9,10,11)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Hello on Win 7 32bit Internet Explorer suddendly stopped filling forms and does not ask to save passwords. No version works (9,10,11). Autocomplete is on. We deleted forms history and unchecked/checked everything there. There is nothing set in the group policy related to IE. 
This is in the registry
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"FormSuggest Passwords"="yes"
"FormSuggest PW Ask"="yes"

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

well, since this is the worst place to ask for something that is not obvious, it's not surprising this question has not been answered.

luckily captain info guy is to the resque

If after all the measures you have taken IE still does not remember or prompt for passwords you need to delete all saved form/password data, preferably from "Internet Options" / "Delete Browsing History". This should fix your problem.